# Switch case on enum type

Tags: ios, swift, enums, switch-statement

I have an issue where I wish to do a switch-case on an enum type (`SearchFilterOptionType`), but for some reason Swift/the Xcode compiler does not recognise the member.

I have the following enum:

```
enum SearchFilterOptionType {
    case Checkbox
    case Selection
    case Interval
    case Text
}
```

And I am able to do the following:

```
if dataElements[0].type == SearchFilterOptionType.Checkbox {
    return
}
```

But if I want to replicate the same with a switch-case I get the error:

> "Enum case 'Checkbox' is not a member of type
> 'SearchFilterOptionType!'"

```
switch dataElements[0].type {
    case SearchFilterOptionType.Checkbox:
        break
            
    default:
        break
}
```

### Added

```
var dataElements: Array<SearchFilterOption>
```

```
struct SearchFilterOption {

    var title: String!
    var type: SearchFilterOptionType!
    
    init(title: String, type: SearchFilterOptionType) {
        self.title = title
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what is `dataElements`, in first if you compare `dataElements[0]` in second case you compare `dataElements[0].type` - these are different values

Comment: Sorry my bad, I actually do compare dataElements[0].type in the if-statement. I have updated the code example

Comment: show what is `dataElements`

Comment: Please add the type of dataElements(its declaration) and declaration of that type

Comment: `dataElements` is an array of objects called `SearchFilterOption`, which have a title (`String`) and a type (`SearchFilterOptionType`).

Comment: is dataElements or the type is optional?

Comment: It looks like you create your `type` like this: `var type: SearchFilterOptionType!` and in this case it is optional type and you need to use switch with unwrapping `switch dataElements[0].type!` In this case, the error will not be but it is wrong, you will need to check that the object is not `nil`

Comment: You are absolutely right!! Thank you!

Comment: Declaring properties as implicit unwrapped optionals is completely useless when using an `init` method with non optional parameters. Remove all exclamation marks in the struct than you get rid of  all those stuff to handle optionals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you declare `type` as optional. Removing `!` (exclamation mark) will help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    switch dataElements[0].type! {
    case SearchFilterOptionType.Checkbox:
        break

    default:
        break
    }
```

Note the `!` in your error message and switch statement